# Argument 'since' on Field 'history' has an invalid value. Expected type 'GitTimestamp'

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

I am using Github's GraphQL (v4) API to make some calls. I am trying to get commits information about a repository, but I am having issues with defining the `since` attribute of the `history` connection of the `Commit` object.

I am getting the following error back:

```
{
    "data": null,
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Argument 'since' on Field 'history' has an invalid value. Expected type 'GitTimestamp'.",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 38,
                    "column": 9
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the extracted part of my GraphQL which is causing the error:

```
query {
    search(query:"is:public", type:REPOSITORY, first:10){       
        edges{
            node{
                ... on Repository{
                    ref(qualifiedName: "master"){
                        target{                         
                            ... on Commit{                              
                                history(first: 10, since:"2017-07-15"){                                 
                                    totalCount
                                    pageInfo{
                                        startCursor
                                        endCursor
                                    }
                                    edges{
                                        node{
                                            ... on Commit{
                                                committedDate
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v4/scalar/gittimestamp/), the `GitTimestamp` scalar is an **ISO-8601** encoded date string. So, what is the problem with my string `"2017-07-15"`? I have also tried the following strings, which none worked.

- 2017/01/01
- 2017.01.01
- 2017-01-01 01:01
- 2017-01-01T01:01
- 2017-01-01 01:01Z
- 2017-01-01T01:01Z

Comment: you need to set hour:minute:second : `2017-07-15T01:01:00`

Comment: Damn seconds... It worked! You can tag your comment as the answer to the problem Bertrand!

Comment: Learned so much in the last few days about GraphQL that I summarized my endeavor with a post on Medium: https://medium.com/@fabiomolinar/using-githubs-graphql-to-retrieve-a-list-of-repositories-their-commits-and-some-other-stuff-ccbbb4e96d78

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify a date in the format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`. The following will work :

- 2017-01-01T01:01:00
- 2017-01-01T01:01:00Z

[Try it in the explorer](https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/?query=%7B%0A%20%20search(query%3A%20%22is%3Apublic%22%2C%20type%3A%20REPOSITORY%2C%20first%3A%2010)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Repository%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ref(qualifiedName%3A%20%22master%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20history(first%3A%2010%2C%20since%3A%20%222017-01-01T01%3A01%3A00%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20totalCount%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20pageInfo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20startCursor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20endCursor%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20edges%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20node%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20...%20on%20Commit%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20committedDate%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

```graphql
{
  search(query: "is:public", type: REPOSITORY, first: 10) {
    edges {
      node {
        ... on Repository {
          ref(qualifiedName: "master") {
            target {
              ... on Commit {
                history(first: 10, since: "2017-01-01T01:01:00") {
                  totalCount
                  pageInfo {
                    startCursor
                    endCursor
                  }
                  edges {
                    node {
                      ... on Commit {
                        committedDate
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```